# Type Mismatch - why i am getting this error?

Tags: spring

My code looks like below:

```
import org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext; 
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public static void main(String args[]) {
    ApplicationContext context = 
        new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring_conf.xml");
}
```

why i am getting this error ?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
Type mismatch: cannot convert from ClassPathXmlApplicationContext to ApplicationContext

at root.Main.main(Main.java:11)
```

Anything i am missing or doing wrong?

Comment: What Spring version are you using ? And please show your imports.

Comment: i'm using eclipse 3.7.2 and spring-framework-3.1.1.RELEASE .

Comment: That (the imports you were asked to include) should answer your question. Next time edit the question with the additional info, though.

Answer (score 8):

Change your first Spring import to:

```
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext
```

This is the correct interface that ClassPathXmlApplicationContext implements.

Answer (score 5):

The import `org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext`  is incorrect, it must be

```
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext
```

Comment: +1 for asking and following up even after someone jumped in ;)

Comment: I think I replied at the same time as the other user ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution.

Replace import statement `org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext;` with the below import statement:

```
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
```

Works for sure, if not Let me know.